# Load css file before js

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I had a internal style followed by a external style. I noticed the page was blank till the external css didn't load. So i changed it to the below code. Now the external css request is made after the js.

Why for both above and how do i make css request before js. Are there any advantages to it(css before js in below code).

```
<body>
  <style>

    body {
        background: #333;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
    headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="build/main.css">';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
  </script>

  <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a [preload](https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/) mostly did the trick

```
<link rel="preload" href="build/main.css" as="style">
```

The browser now made the request for css. Then it makes a call for js. Then it adds CSS tag to the head. Finally, tries to remakes the call to get CSS but since the call is in progress or done it just loads it. There is an issue of FOUC though if CSS takes times.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout in a function which is called when the body loads.

```
<body onload="loadPage()">
```

**JS**

```
function loadPage() {
//code to load css
setTimeout(function() {
//code to load js
}, 1);
}
```

I think that would work. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to load the style before anything because it's the visual of your page. It's the first thing the user see.

You change css too along with DOM using javascript. So it is preferred to load css first.

Answer (score 0):

This happends because a page is rendered from top to bottom. So I suppose that browser renders you inline styles and goes executing inlines script which uppends link to a style. Then it goes further and executes external script. And after that it loads your newly appended stylesheet.

So, I'd be too naive to ask but why don't you just put your stylesheet link into the head?

Comment: "I noticed the page was blank till the external CSS didn't load. So, i changed it to the below code. Now the external CSS request is made after the js."

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should just put your css files like normal people do :). but if you really want to make it happen, it's gonna get as ugly as this code gets:

```
<script>
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'style.css');
    var sheet = "sheet", cssRules = "cssRules";
    if (!('sheet' in link)) {
        sheet = "styleSheet";
        cssRules = "rules";
    }
    var waitForCSS = setInterval(function() {
        if (link[sheet]) {

            // now you can load your javascript files here like I did with CSS
            // or just use any js code you want.


            clearInterval(waitForCSS);
        }
    }, 10);
    head.appendChild(link);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is

```html
<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="build/main.css">
  <style>
    body {
      background: #333;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--
Rest of your code in body

//-->
<!--Body is going to end after the below //-->
<script>
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
   var sc=document.createElement('script');
   sc.src="build/polyfills.js";
   document.head.appendChild(sc);
  });
</script>
</body>
```

A webpage is parsed from top to bottom.

So, try put the `style` in your `head` tag and place the `scripts` in just before end of `body` tag

In the script,

add an eventlistener to window when the Dom content Loaded, make a script tag, append src and append it to Head.